# Generic Dictionary value is an Generic Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'd like to create a class which contains a generic dictionary which value is an generic dictionary as below:

```
class DList<T>
{
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<K, T>> Dic;
    public Init<K,T>()
    {
        Dic = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<K, T>>();
        Dic.Add("Name", new Dictionary<string, T>());
        Dic.Add("Id", new Dictionary<int, T>());
    }
}
```

How can I implement this? Thanks a lot

Comment: You've done exactly what you're asking how to do. The only problem is that you're adding random types as the key to the value dictionary, rather than K.

Comment: Do you want the value dictionaries to have a key of `K` or some dynamic type?

Comment: What is the actual issue you are trying to solve? you should typically try to avoid cases like your example, since it will likely be difficult to work with. How are you supposed to know to use `Dict["Id"][1]` instead of `Dict["Id"]["1"]`.

Comment: Looking at Dictionary<string, T> and Dictionary<int, T> it looks like you want a dictionary with named values that is kind of type safe. You could just use dictionary<string,object> to save named values. What you end up with is named dictionaries<K,T>. In that case maybe try Dictionary<string,Dictionary<Type, object>> or use Dictionary<string, (Type, object)>. But you will not get object as a generic type so you will need to do Type inspection on each value.... to me this seems kind of a pointless structure.

Comment: Dictionary<string, dynamic>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dynamic works. What I need is almost like a multi-keys Dictionary.

```
public class DList<T> : IEnumerable
{
    private List<T> list;
    private Dictionary<string, dynamic> dic;

    public T this[int i] => list[i];

    public dynamic this[string j] => dic[j];

    public int Count => list.Count;

    public DList(params string[] properties)
    {
        this.list = new List<T>();
        this.dic = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
        foreach (var item in properties)
        {
            this.dic.Add(item, new Dictionary<dynamic, T>());
        }
    }

    public void Add(T t)
    {
        list.Add(t);
        foreach (var item in dic)
        {
            dynamic d = t.GetType()
                .GetField(item.Key)
                .GetValue(t);
            if (item.Value.ContainsKey(d))
                continue;
            item.Value.Add(d, t);
        }
    }

    public T Get(string key, dynamic s)
    {
        return dic[key][s];
    }

    public T Get(int index)
    {
        return list[index];
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        this.list.Clear();
        foreach(var item in dic)
        {
            item.Value.Clear();
        }
    }

    public void Sort(Comparison<T> Compare)
    {
        list.Sort(Compare);
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return list.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class DList<K, T>
{
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<K, T>> Dic;
    public DList()
    {
        Dic = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<K, T>>();
        Dic.Add("Name", new Dictionary<K, T>());
        Dic.Add("Id", new Dictionary<K, T>());
    }
}


class DList2<K, T>
{
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<object, T>> Dic;
    public DList2()
    {
        Dic = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<object, T>>();
        Dic.Add("Name", new Dictionary<object, T>());
        Dic.Add("Id", new Dictionary<object, T>());
    }
}
```

If you know `K` upfront, use the `DList` approach. If you want to use `string`, `int` etc for `K`, use the approach in `DList2`. The inner dictionary will work just fine with keys of type `int`, `string`, etc, even if its key is declared as `object`.

Comment: Integers would be boxed by using `object` as the key for the inner dictionary.